# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AccountState'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented my SDK

from

```
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

to

```
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Now this error occurs on the super(null)

```
The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AccountState'.
```

Here is my code:

```
class AccountBloc extends Bloc<AccountEvent, AccountState> {
  final UserDataRepository? userDataRepository;

  AccountBloc({required this.userDataRepository}) : super(null);

  AccountState get initialState => AccountInitial();
```

May I know how will I fix my issue? Thanks!

Comment: Set `UserDataRepository? userDataRepository;` in your bloc initialisation.

Comment: can you share the super class constructor prototype?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I have updated my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial state is non-null and you have just activated null-safety. So you need to pass a non-null value for the initial state:

```
AccountBloc({required this.userDataRepository}) : super(AccountInitial());
```

By the way, this:

```
AccountState get initialState => AccountInitial();
```

has been obsolete for a while, which is why you have to pass something to the super constructor now. I guess you kinda winged it back when that change was due? Always read the patchnotes when there are breaking changes. They tell you what to do.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I actually try to find it in the document but unsuccessful to find this exactly. Anyway, thanks again.